# MediaPlayer with custom socketFactory

Tags: android, https, media-player

I have a HTTPS MEDIA server with **self signed certificate** from which I want to stream audio in my Android app. As per this link from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), to allow self signed certificate, I have generated a certificate by reading the .crt file, created a keystore with this certificate and initialized this keyStore to a TrustManagerFactory.

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    Log.d(TAG, "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

The link describes an example to use this custom SSLContext with an HttpsURLConnection object.

```
// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

But in my app for HTTP, I'm using `MediaPlayer` class by setting the audio link as  below.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(address); //address is a String variable like http://example.com/audio.aac
```

The question is, how do i use the above SSLContext's `socketFactory` object with the MediaPlayer, so that the MediaPlayer could use HTTPS audio source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this custom `SSLContext` connection, we have to set the `socketFactory` object to the `HttpsURLConnection` before providing the source to the media player.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

This allows the `MediaPlayer` to use the connection with our self signed certificate.

Other than this, I also had to provide a custom `HostnameVerifier` implementation to verify the subjectAlternateNames manually.

```
final HostnameVerifier hv =
  HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    return hv.verify("www.youdomainname.com", session);
  }
};
```

And this custom `HostnameVerifier` could be linked to the `MediaPlayer` by the below code.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```